# IP Warming strategy for new company

Tags: marketing-cloud, sender-authentication-package

Working with a client that has not actually launched yet but anticipates sends for both commercial and transactional to be in the 3-4 figures per day in the first month.

We have a dedicated IP and would like to know what the strategy would be for this case?

Answer (score 1):

There is no absolute science of how to conduct the IP-warm up. I have been following the guidelines in the documentation and haven't run into any bigger problems.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_ip_address_warming.htm&type=5